# Are the roots of Bessel functions closed under multiplication?

Tags: roots, bessel-functions, music-theory

In terms of eigenfunctions, a circular drum vibrates in angular velocity of $\lambda _{mn}$, the nth positive root of the Bessel function $J_m(x)$, $m = 0, 1, \cdots$.

If they are closed under multiplication, that would mean it's possible to have consonance between drums. Are they?

Comment: Of course not...  In fact, if we omit $0$ it is probably true that no product from the set $\lambda_{mn}$ is again in the set.

Comment: @GEdgar Of course, I demand a proof.